# jQuery conditional validation for minlength and maxlength

Tags: jquery-validate, conditional-statements

I am using jQuery validation plugin and this question is about conditional validation of minlength and maxlength rules.

I have a dropdown list and a textbox. If the user selects a particular value in dropdown list the textbox minlength should be 13 characters,maxlength should be 19 characters. For other dropdown values minlength and maxlength should be 16 characters.

Help appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Validation maxlength parameter based on conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721427/jquery-validation-maxlength-parameter-based-on-conditional)  The proposed dupe is not as old as this page, but it contains a superior / more articulate solution which researchers will ultimately find more useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this

```
rules:
 {
     ControlName:
      {
          minlength:function (element) {
              you can write your code to check your conditions
          }
      }
 }
```