# jQuery Validation maxlength parameter based on conditional

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to change the maxlength of a textbox using jQuery Validation based on a condition.

Code

```
 SSN: { required: true, minlength: 9, maxlength: 9 }
```

How do I change the maxlength based on an if-else condition?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation conditional rule makes input never valid - valid always returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953078/jquery-validation-conditional-rule-makes-input-never-valid-valid-always-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a ternary expression be what you want ?

```
SSN: { required: true, minlength: 9, maxlength: ((condition)?true:false) }
```

Exemple :

```
SSN: { required: true, minlength: 9, maxlength: ((my_var=="short")?13:17) }
```

Would print 13 if the condition is met, otherwise 17

Edit: Correcting the max lenght so it is bigger than the min lenght.

Comment: You must `return` the parameter from inside a `function()` and the parameter for `maxlength` could never be a boolean. Your answer is completely broken: http://jsfiddle.net/nxtbzuys

Comment: Where do you see a boolean ? Its juste a ternary expression where true and false mean where to put the maxlenght number in case the condition is true or not, as in the exemple 9 or 5

Comment: Um... `true` and `false` are called "boolean" values.   It's nonsense, because you can never declare `true` or `false` on the `maxlength` method.   Regardless, using your second line of code, the answer is still broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/g6cLj69L/  You also cannot have a `maxlength` less  than the `minlength`.   Just a really poor answer with broken code and problematic usage issues.

Comment: No, it's not.  [In your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny6ahnh0/1/), the `maxlength` is ***always*** `15` no matter what the condition!

Comment: I have no idea what you were thinking, because everything you've posted is broken.

Comment: Hii @RomainDerie.. will this solution work for selectboxes ?
Actually am trying this on selectbox, but its not working as needed.. Is there any other way to do for selectboxes ?

Answer (score -1):

As this [doc](http://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method) shows, I think that you can change `maxlength` by the maxlength method :

```
$( "#yourTextBox" ).validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: function(){
        return condition ? valueIfTrue, valueIfFalse;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT : As @Sparky pointed out, the configuration cannot be reinitailized. So the `maxlength` should be changed by a callback function.

Comment: That's like the code he already has.  He wants to change it dynamically based on a conditional.

Comment: @Sparky, Hello, my answer just tell him that he can use this code to change the value of `maxlength` on the fly. I can't see the difference between your answer and my answer. You have just given an example of condiction. Since the we can have thousands of conditions, or this code can be called in the event handler, I just didn't given it out.

Comment: Nonsense.  You **cannot** call `.validate()` more than one time to initialize the plugin, nor can you call it on the text box to change rules.  If you call `.validate()` again, it is completely ignored by the plugin.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/d2hfb2be/